# why multiple processes for one application and consume so much resources

Tags: linux, process, sublime-text-3

[image]
As the screenshot (`htop`) shows, there are multiple processes for sublime_3 application, why is that? I only opened 1 application with multiple tabs.

In addition to that, why are the processes taking so many resources (9.8G virtual memory each process)? The files that I opened with sublime are all regular text files, not big, at most 300 lines per file.

This basically causes my desktop freeze.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's just multiple threads of the same process – they all share the same memory. Press <kbd>Shift+H</kbd> to toggle showing non-main threads. (You might also want to press <kbd>F2</kbd> in htop, then under "Display options" enable "Show custom thread names" plus "Display threads in a different color".)

[image]

Large amounts of "VIRT" – virtual memory – are completely normal. This is just the *address range* of that process, and most of it consists either of "on-demand" areas (not using any RAM as long as they're blank) or memory-mapped files (stored on disk). Certain runtimes map more memory upfront than others (especially web browsers use it as a security mechanism), but that just reserves the address range and doesn't consume actual RAM before it's needed.

Instead, you should be concerned about the "RES" column, which indicates amount of RAM that is *actually* in use by the process. In your picture, the actual memory usage of Sublime Text is **6486 MB (6.4 GB)**. (Again, your picture shows threads, so it's "only" 1x6486 MB across all items, not 12x6486.)

With that being said, I don't actually know *why* Sublime Text needs such large amounts of memory (6G is still quite a lot). But it seems that [many other people have the same problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=sublime+text+memory+usage). A very common cause among forum posts seems to be having a Git repository right on your homedir (i.e. ~/.git), so you should check if you have that. You can also start sublime from a terminal and watch for suspicious messages it may output.